# How can i pass parameter as a dictionary to url using post method

Tags: ios, objective-c

hello friends I have pass JSON parameter using post method I am tired to do this code..

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"cmscontent" : @{
                                         @"access_name"   : @"about u",
                                         }
                                 };


    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:nil];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://.........."]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *dataTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest: request
                                                             fromData: data completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)

                                        {
                                            NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                                            NSLog(@"%@", json);
                                        }];

    [dataTask resume];
```

and my json dictionary parameter is..

```
 {
  "cmscontent": 
    {
          "access_name": "about us"
    }
}
```

so please tell me how can i pass this types of parameter??

Answer (score 1):

**Prerequisites**

1. Make sure your API method is `POST` in backend.
2. Make sure your API method accepts `JSON` data.
3. Make sure all the parameter name are identical to your API method.

**Use following method to POST data to API**

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:@"http://....."];

NSDictionary *params= @{@"cmscontent" :
                                    @{
                                        @"access_name"   : @"about u"
                                     }
                             };
 NSError *err = nil;
 NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&err];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if([data length] > 0)
                           {
                               NSError *err = nil;
                               NSDictionary *dictResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];
                               NSLog(@"[%@]", dictResponse);                                  
                           }
                           else{
                               NSLog(@"Failed To Get Response for : %@",params);
                           }
                       }];
```

Comment: Before you do anything have you checked all the `Prerequisites` i mentioned? can you post your API URL?

Comment: i asked 2 questions, Before you do anything have you checked all the Prerequisites i mentioned?

Comment: then it should be working, given method is 100% working, check your environment and API end. There is no issue in method if `Prerequisites` are clear or else provide your `URL`. Also `post error` which you are getting in response.

Comment: {
  "cmscontent": 
    {
          "access_name": "about us"
    }
} 
i will pass this types of dictionary but in this extra semi colon added..
i think this is problem..

Comment: is it working now? if now post error which you get in response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104144/discussion-between-dipen-panchasara-and-nilesh-parmar).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but converting `NSDictionary` object into `NSString` object , then post this string object as parameter like other string parameters. I hope this will help you...

```
NSString *postDictionaryAsSting = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictObj options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];


NSData *requestData = [postDictionaryAsSting dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (connection) {
 receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
```

Comment: @Jigar where this showing error. dictObj & url is variable which you use in your code. Its only for understanding that you have to use dictionary object and your url in place of that. And retain is used in case of non-ARC.

Comment: here this line data is display error. receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

Comment: if you are using ARC remove retain key. This will solve error